# Installation of symfony2 in ubuntu14.04

Tags: 14.04, php

I want to install Symfony2 in Ubuntu 14.04, What should I do ? thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install Symfony 2.8 for long-term support open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install curl
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
sudo curl -LsS https://symfony.com/installer -o /usr/local/bin/symfony
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/symfony
```

To create a new Symfony 2.8 application, run this command:

```
symfony new my_project_name lts # use the most recent long-term support version
```

Symfony leverages the internal PHP web server (available since PHP 5.4) to run applications while developing them. Therefore, running a Symfony application is a matter of browsing to the project directory and executing this command:

```
cd my_project_name/
php bin/console server:run
```

Then, open your browser and access the `http://localhost:8000/` URL to see the Symfony welcome page:

[image]